# Row sums by groups through index in columns

Tags: r, rowsum

I am running R in Rstudio.

I have a data frame that has the following columns:
y0, y1, y2, y3, .... yn   and yb0, yb1, yb2, yb3... ybn
where n could be as large as 1000.

I want to do row sums such that
y0=y0+yb0,  y1=y1+yb1, y2=y2+yb2...., yn=yn+ybn

So, it is like updating y0, y1, y2.... yn.

I tried using rowwise() with mutate( across ())  but not working.
tmpA is my data with the y's and the yb's

```
tmpB <- tmpA %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("y"), ~ . + get(paste0("yb", substr(cur_column(), 2))), .names = "yc{substr(cur_column(), 2)}")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I don't know if the codes make sense but I've got errors and not sure how to fix it.
I want to keep all variables in the original dataset but drop the 'yb's in the output.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `starts_with("y")` includes all columns, both starting with "y" and "yb"...maybe you could try something like: `mutate(tmpA, across(matches("y\\d+")) + across(starts_with("yb")))`...note this assumes same number of columns available for both "y" and "yb"...

Answer (score 0):

While it is generally frowned on `for` cycles, here it would add to the simplicity and readability of the solution.

Since you didn't provide sample data, we don't know if `n` is known beforehand or if `y1`, `y2`, ..., are necessarily sequential. So I will go with a simple solution and assume they are and `n` is known. This means that the numbers will go strictly from `1` to `n`

```
n = 1000 # assume `n` is known beforehand
for(i in seq_len(n)){
  df[paste0("y", i)] = df[paste0("y", i)] + df[paste0("yb", i)]
}
```

The `df` will be updated in place.

Comment: Thank you so much and I think I was thinking too complicated.

Comment: It is important to learn `base` alongside `tidyverse`. Some operations in tidyerse are too complicated and simpler in base. Other times it is the other way around. If it solved your problem, don't forget to upvote the answer and, after some time has passed (lets say a day or a few hours), mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have something like this,

```
> df
  y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10 yb0 yb1 yb2 yb3 yb4 yb5 yb6 yb7 yb8 yb9 yb10
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21   22
2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21   22
3  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21   22
4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21   22
```

Since R is vectorized, which means it can handle arithmetic operations on data structures of different dimensions, from simple vectors to complex matrices and arrays, you can simply add the two sub-dataframes. Identify the respective columns using regular expressions in `grep()`.

```
> df[grep('y\\d+', names(df))] + df[grep('yb\\d+', names(df))]
  y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10
1 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31  33
2 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31  33
3 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31  33
4 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31  33
```

Note, this requires *y* and *yb* columns in the same order. If you're not sure, you can check this using

```
stopifnot(lapply(c('y\\d+', 'yb\\d+'), grep, x=names(df), value=TRUE) |> 
            lapply(gsub, pattern='\\D', replacement='') |> 
            do.call(what='identical'))
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(y0 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), y1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    y2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), y3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), y4 = c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L), y5 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), y6 = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L
    ), y7 = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), y8 = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), y9 = c(10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L), y10 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), yb0 = c(12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L), yb1 = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), yb2 = c(14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L), yb3 = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), yb4 = c(16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L), yb5 = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), yb6 = c(18L, 
    18L, 18L, 18L), yb7 = c(19L, 19L, 19L, 19L), yb8 = c(20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L), yb9 = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), yb10 = c(22L, 
    22L, 22L, 22L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

**tidyverse**

```r
df <- data.frame(
          y0 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
          y1 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
          y2 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
          y3 = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
          y4 = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
          y5 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L),
          y6 = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L),
          y7 = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L),
          y8 = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L),
          y9 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L),
         y10 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L),
         yb0 = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L),
         yb1 = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L),
         yb2 = c(14L, 14L, 14L, 14L),
         yb3 = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L),
         yb4 = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L),
         yb5 = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L),
         yb6 = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L),
         yb7 = c(19L, 19L, 19L, 19L),
         yb8 = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L),
         yb9 = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L),
        yb10 = c(22L, 22L, 22L, 22L)
      )

library(tidyverse)
library(glue)

nmb <- str_extract(names(df), "\\d+") %>% unique()

map_dfc(nmb, ~rowSums(df[str_detect(names(df), glue("[a-z]{.x}$"))])) %>% 
  set_names(nm = str_c("y", nmb))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 11
#>      y0    y1    y2    y3    y4    y5    y6    y7    y8    y9   y10
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    13    15    17    19    21    23    25    27    29    31    33
#> 2    13    15    17    19    21    23    25    27    29    31    33
#> 3    13    15    17    19    21    23    25    27    29    31    33
#> 4    13    15    17    19    21    23    25    27    29    31    33
```

or

```r
df %>%
  mutate(idrows = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -idrows,
    names_to = c(".value", "set"),
    names_pattern = "([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)"
  ) %>%
  mutate(res = rowSums(pick(starts_with("y")))) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = idrows,
    names_from = set,
    values_from = res,
    names_prefix = "y"
```